# How do i load the triples from the test.ttl file in docker-virtuoso?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, virtuoso

I am very beginner to docker and want to load the triples of a test.ttl file which I want to add the virtuoso graph.

I have tried using the following git link,
https://github.com/joernhees/docker-virtuoso/blob/master/README.md

```
docker run -it \
    -v /host/db/dir:/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-7 \
    -v /data/dbpedia:/import:ro \
    joernhees/virtuoso import 'http://dbpedia.org'
```

But this will not even load the graph.

What I want is to load the `Test.ttl` file data to virtuoso using Docker.

In virtuoso without docker, there is an option to load the triples using upload `Quad Store Upload` option.

I don't understand in docker how do I load the `test.ttl` file to virtuoso graph and make an IRI, i.e., `HTTP:/localhost:8890/testgraph`

Please give me your suggestions and thoughts on this issue.anybody help me on this issue.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the third-party [docker-virtuoso](https://github.com/joernhees/docker-virtuoso/issues) project; not with Docker nor Virtuoso, in themselves. More, this appears to be a failure to read the cited document which explains several of the arguments to docker, which need changes for your deployment. That said, once you have Virtuoso running in your Docker container, you should be able to just use the normal features, like the [Bulk Loader](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader).

Comment: You might also benefit from reading over some documentation from the Virtuoso team, such as [How to Deploy Virtuoso in a Docker Container](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtuosoDocker).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TallTed.I have tried as you suggested and pull the image OpenLink/virtuoso_opensource from docker hub now its working fine.Now I have tried the example from the virtuoso document  https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample9. In that, I have found only the triples are inserted into the graph.what if I have to insert a file test.ttl triples.what's the way to do that I didn't find on google.Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I commented previously, "once you have Virtuoso running in your Docker container, you should be able to just use the normal features, like the [Bulk Loader](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader)." If that's not suitable for whatever reason, there are [many other ways to load RDF to a Virtuoso instance](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert). If you have further questions, they should likely be asked on their own, [per site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).